# How to substitute zeros for NAs in R

Tags: r, na, substitution, zero

I have a dataframe with a numeric column. How can I substitute all zeros for NAs? I tried

```
 mtcars <- lapply(mtcars, function(v) {v[v==0] <- NA; v} )
```

and

```
 mtcars <- lapply(mtcars, function(v) {v[v==0] <- "NA"; v} )
```

but then the data are no longer numeric. Does anyone have a suggestion, please? Thank you.

Comment: `mtcars[mtcars==0] <- NA`

Comment: Thank you so much! Apologies for the duplicate question. I had found the NA -> 0 question, but not this one. Thanks again.